# Mysql несколько условий с одного столбца

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет заметил такой странный глюк в MYSQL что условие And не работает с одной страницы.
Имеется для примера простая таблица где указано посещение посетителей той или иной комнаты в барделе(шутка).

[image: логи клиентов]

Необходимо найти клиентов которые были в 1 и в 2 комнате. Я делаю очевидный запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE room =1 and room =2
```

и получаю фигу.
Причем в документации такие случае нигде не показанны, кроме как увидел у оракла что вроде как можно. Использую mysql 5.7 можете помочь советом?

Answer (score 0):

оператор AND в данном случае будет искать выполнение обоих условий в каждой строке, т.е. он ожидает, что одна строка будет иметь как значение комнаты 1, так и 2, что невозможно.
если вы хотите вывести клиентов, которые были либо там, либо там, то воспользуйтесь оператором OR.
если вас интересуют клиенты, которые посетили обе комнаты, вариантов решения несколько, например, обратиться к таблице 2 раза, выбирая разные номера комнат при разных обращениях, и соединить их при помощи иннер джоин по полю клиента

Comment: *например, обратиться к таблице 2 раза, выбирая разные номера комнат при разных обращениях, и соединить их при помощи иннер джоин по полю клиента* Бесперспективный подход. Нерасширяемый.

Answer (score 0):

Комнаты в барделе(шутка) - вынести в отдельную таблицу.

Вот придумал костыль -

```sql
select name, sum(room) 
from Test 
where room in (1,2) 
group by name 
having sum(room) = 3;
```

НО

если Иван два раза сходит к одной и тойже во 2 или 1. Уже не будет работать. Нужно выбрать както уникальные 1 и 2 и потом их просумировать. Подзапросом, возможно. Тогда норм.

Подумаю на досуге.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут нужно было бы попробовать что-то вроде `having count(distinct(room)) = 2`, если `SQL` такие условия позволяет.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить `OR` вместо `and` и запрос будет правильно работать:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE room = 1 OR room = 2;
```

Comment: Не будет он правильно работать -- смысл исходного вопроса в том, чтобы найти юзеров, которые были **в обеих комнатах**, а `OR` вернёт пользователей, побывавших хотя бы в одной.